# Improve Update Statement Performance

Tags: sql-server, performance, group-by, sql-update

I am building SQL Update Query
This query has to show top Paid vendors and the details of the payments for each vendor per month, and at the same time the total payments for the vendor

```
VendorTable
Vendor varchar(100)
Month   Date
MonthlyAmt   int
TotalAmt int
```

-

```
Vendor   Month   MonthlyAmt   TotalAmt
Vendor1  Jan-15  $100         NULL
Vendor2  Mar-16  $250         NULL
Vendor3  Sep-16  $300         NULL
Vendor1  Dec-16  $140         NULL
Vendor2  Feb-17  $210         NULL
Vendor1  Apr-17  $400         NULL
Vendor3  Aug-17  $420         NULL
Vendor2  Nov-17  $330         NULL
Vendor2  Mar-18  $110         NULL
Vendor1  May-18  $230         NULL
```

Example of the end result

```
Vendor   Month   MonthlyAmt   TotalAmt
Vendor1  Jan-15  $100         $870
Vendor2  Mar-16  $250         $900
Vendor3  Sep-16  $300         $720
Vendor1  Dec-16  $140         $870
Vendor2  Feb-17  $210         $900
Vendor1  Apr-17  $400         $870
Vendor3  Aug-17  $420         $900
Vendor2  Nov-17  $330         $900
Vendor2  Mar-18  $110         $900
Vendor1  May-18  $230         $870
```

My Update looks like this
but it is taking very long time to be processed
I wonder if there is a much faster way to do that

```
UPDATE VendorTable 
SET TotalAmt = (SELECT SUM(MonthlyAmt) FROM VendorTable B WHERE B.Vendor = A.Vendor)
from VendorTable A
```

Comment: I don't think it would speed it up, but if you stored the data in a temp tables, you could update  the table in chunks, which would reduce the likely hood of failure and prevent super long runs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like...

```
WITH X AS (
    SELECT Vendor , SUM(MonthlyAmt) AS TotalAmtCalculated
    FROM VendorTable
    GROUP BY Vendor
)
UPDATE t 
 SET t.TotalAmt = x.TotalAmtCalculated
FROM VendorTable t 
INNER JOIN x ON t.Vendor = x.Vendor
```

Your query is slow because your inner select s getting executed for each row returned by the outer update query.

Also check if there are any indexes on the table with the `TotalAmt` column in them, those indexes will also slow down your updates.

Comment: Many thanks, the performance improved from almost 5 minutes to less than 10 seconds. Thanks again

Comment: No problem, glad to help.